# Conditional WHERE clause with operator in statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that I'm trying to do a conditional WHERE clause on. I believe the solution is easy but for some reason it's escaping me.

What I'm trying to achieve is: if a ID (@pbid in this case) is passed to the stored procedure I only want to return a single record matching that parameter otherwise I'd like to return all results in the table.

Here is the what I have come up with and it's obviously not going to work because I'm trying to do an equals evaluation at PBID *(PBID =)* and  I'm looking to conditionally make that

```
 where pb.PBID =
    CASE WHEN @pbid is not null THEN 
    @pbid  --just return results with this ID
    ELSE
    is not null --return all results
  END
```

If it was C# or something I'd write it like:

```
if(intPBID > 0) --parameter set, only return results with that param
{
   pb.PBID = intPBID
}
else
{
  pb.PBID > 0 --return everything
}
```

I hope this isn't too confusing and I'd appreciate any feedback.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about performance implications, but I typically end up doing something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (@pbid IS NULL OR pb.PBID = @pbid)
```

Comment: I knew it was insanely simple. That worked beautifully. I was overthinking it I suspect!

Comment: Here's the performance piece: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/

Comment: @scsimon I realize this could potentially be a problem but it's being using for a very small data set. Thank you for the info though.

Comment: No worries at all @Waragi I use the same method Matt posted frequently. I was just providing him a link about the performance since he mentioned it.